# How would one differentiate Einstein summation and matrix entry notation?

Tags: matrices, tensors, index-notation

In [this](https://youtu.be/8OMT2xKQaQg?t=2843) video on Tensor calculus(timestamped), the professor explains how the matrix entry is written in a tensor-like notation:

$$\text{(i,j)}^{th}\text{ entry of matrix A}=A_{ij}=A_j^i$$

Later in the video, he also proceeds to explain why $A_i^i$ represents the trace of the matrix, which is a natural consequence of the Einstein summation notation.

The question here is, how would you differentiate the k$^{th}$ diagonal entry of the matrix, $A_{kk}$, from it being a live index hence representing a sum?

Comment: It's very simple. If the Einstein summation convention is in play, you have to say, *in words*, "no summation." (When I taught, I always wrote summation symbols just to avoid this problem.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah I see, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @TedShifrin Also please let me use this opportunity to mention that I've been self studying your book on multivariable maths and it's absolutely wonderful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, one never refers to a diagonal element of a matrix because it is something that depends on the coordinate system. Einstein's notation only lets you write complete expressions that denote things that do not depend on that.

If you for some reason need to write something that does not satisfy that condition it is useful to be explicit independently of what notation you are using!